# What to say instead of “Ladies and Gentlemen”?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms, expression-choice

What do I say instead of *Ladies and Gentlemen*  if there are many men and only one woman present? Should I say:

1. ***Lady*** and Gentlemen
2. *Gentlemen and Lady*
3. *Madam and Gentlemen*
4. or something else?

Comment: What is the context? Are you presenting a show? Are you the master of ceremonies? In which case, if there is only one member of public present I'd check my agenda, see I got my dates mixed up  and then ask the lady/madam/miss/young lady if she had come to the right venue.

Comment: Its a conference and I have the start speech

Comment: no,there are many men but only one woman

Comment: Just use the idiomatic *"Ladies and Gentlemen"*

Comment: is it wrong to use lady and gentlemen?

Comment: Hello! Everyone.
Hello (name of woman  if you know) and all the Gentlemen. 
Hello Ma'm and all the Gentlemen.

Comment: An answer [there](https://news.google.com/newspapers?nid=1356&dat=19890417&id=FrdPAAAAIBAJ&sjid=1gYEAAAAIBAJ&pg=4983,1633587&hl=fr), where the author favors "Madam and gentlemen".

Comment: Borrow a page from my platoon sergeant's book: "Hey, listen up!"

Comment: It would be 'wrong' (rather sound strange) to say 'Lady and gentlemen' or Ladies and gentleman' or whatever permutation in order to specify number. 'Ladies and Gentlemen is a set phrase for an audience. It is comical when an intro "gentlemen' is given and the speaker realizes there is one woman, and fllows up with '...and lady'. It's comical and grammatically correct, but not what you _should_ do. Just use 'Ladies and gentlemen' and move on.

Comment: @Mitch I'm old enough to remember the time when it was unusual to see women at professional meetings - early 1960s. And if there was just one lady, the address would be *lady and gentlemen* . It was perfectly idiomatic at that time.

Comment: @WS2 sure but it sounds perfectly unidiomatic nowadays. 'Dear white people and one black guy', 'Welcome Englishmen and that one Scot in the back' 'I'd like to thank all the talented excellent people I love. Oh, and Bob'.

Comment: @WS2 How about in the context of a crowd/audience made up of many women and just one man? Would the address be, "Ladies and Gentleman" or "Ladies, Sir"?

Comment: @Mitch Those are quite absurd analogies. Nobody says *black people and white people*, nor *Englishmen and Scotsmen*, so it is of little surprise that they wouldn't say what you suggested. I see nothing whatever wrong with *ladies and gentleman* nor vice versa. Who on earth could take exception to it?

Answer (score 1):

"Ladies and gentlemen" is a stock phrase that won't seem remarkable even if there's only one member of a particular gender present. Anything you construct based on this will only draw attention to the imbalance and will draw attention to your error if you've miscounted or interpreted a name wrong.

So if you don't want to be numerically incorrect, use a completely different approach. A simple "good morning everyone" would work. The situations in which you can get away with a former colleague kicking off a meeting with a solemn "dearly beloved,  we are gathered here to commemorate..." are more limited.

Answer (score -1):

Consider, [***Gentlemen, Madam***](https://www.getyarn.io/yarn-clip/ba8a2e23-7387-4931-8666-5a07818481b2)

> *Gentlemen, Madam, I'm going to ask you to leave now.*
>
> [Very Private Duty](https://books.google.fr/books?id=FfdsRU_pE1UC&pg=PT142&dq=%22gentlemen,+Madam+I%22&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjh8Mjysp_MAhUK1BoKHWnLChs4ChDoAQhPMAc#v=onepage&q=%22gentlemen%2C%20Madam%20I%22&f=false)
>
> *The Chairman: Gentlemen, Madam. I understand that last night you were unfortunately unable to question all the witnesses.*
>
> [Minutes of Proceedings and Evidence of the Standing Committee on External Affairs and National Defence](https://books.google.fr/books?id=MuUeAAAAMAAJ&q=%22gentlemen,+Madam+I%22&dq=%22gentlemen,+Madam+I%22&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwieoezktp_MAhVMuhoKHaiSDaQ4ChDoAQhXMAg)

Comment: Post this answer on the older question. Here: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/131089/50044

Comment: @Mari-LouA  The older question is about how addressing "two" persons of different sex, not many men and only one woman,

Comment: nitpicking at its finest... bah, humbug

Comment: @NVZ I read the accepted answer, but I can't seem to see "Gentlemen, Madam" as a suggestion...

Comment: Even the OP accepted this as duplicate, didn't you notice before single-handedly reopening it?

Comment: @NVZ What I mean is, I'd never address a woman as "lady" as it may have a condescending tone (e.g. "Hey, Lady!")  or implies nobility.

Comment: +1 your edits improved the answer.

Comment: If you are addressing a woman directly, "ma'am" is the alternative used in AmE (but becoming rarer), but is really off as a in introduction to a speech.

Comment: @Mitch Thanks for the input. I'll edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: @Elian 'Gentlemen, Madam' though very formal, does sound idiomatic for addressing people directly.

Answer (score -1):

Everyone.
Hello (name of woman  if you know) and all the Gentlemen. 
Hello Ma'm and all the Gentlemen.